# New Magento1 patch for php 7.2 - how to make it work with Magento 1.13?

Tags: magento-1, patches, php-7, ee-1.13, php-7.2

I am dealing with an old website with a lot of custom modules running on Magento 1.13 (obviously, EE). I am very excited to see official support for php7.2 - however, I can see that the patch is applicable only for 1.14 version.

What differences between 1.13 and 1.14 can prevent/make the application of said patch harder? Is there a way, open-source project, or best practice recommendations that would allow me to ensure that at least core Magento wouldn't break when applying it, despite running older version?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply the patch, but most likely it will fail, because it will try to change lines in files that are not identical between EE1.13 and EE1.14.

You could of course try to apply it manually, but that's not something I would personally look forward to :)

Maybe your best bet is to check the Release Notes of 1.13 and 1.14:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ee1.13_release-notes.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ee1.14_release-notes.html

...and try to update your Magento instance before you apply the said patch.